# Rails - Deleting unsaved associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Lets say I have a user model that has many articles.

If I call user.articles.new many times I will have many unsaved article objects associated with the user. They are visible when you run user.articles. Calling user.save will save all of this unsaved records.

How can I delete unsaved records? I plan on calling user.save but I don't want those unsaved records to be there

Comment: Why are you calling `user.articles.new` many times if you don't want to create new article records?

Answer (score 5):

I use the following workaround `before_validation :remove_blank_articles!`:

```
class User
  has_many :articles

  validates_associated :articles

  before_validation :remove_blank_articles!

  private
    def remove_blank_articles!
      self.articles = articles - articles.select(&:blank?)
      true
    end
end

class Article
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :title, :body

  def blank?
    title.blank? and body.blank?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be `user.articles.delete_if{|a| a.new_record?}`, but this sounds like a workaround for the actual problem, to which @regulatethis points in your question's comment.

Comment: That doesn't actually destroy the record. Tried it using console. If there's no easy way to do it I should probably just fix the root problem

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be calling `reload`. In your case, you can try

```
user.reload
```

All those unsaved articles should be removed.