# Mongoid remove unsaved embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using mongoid for an app where the user is the parent document, and pretty much all other information is embedded in the user. So for instance, my controller `#new` action for a `Relationship` belonging to the user looks something like:

```rb
def new
  @relationship = current_user.relationships.new(friend_id: params[:fid])
  @relationship.validate
end
```

Because I run validations on the relationship that will show up in the view and some of those validations need to be able to reference the parent, I can't just call `@relationship = Relationship.new(friend_id: params[:fid])`, but having instantiated this relationship in the user's relationship array, it's now hanging out in there, even if the user decides they don't want to make a new relationship after all and they go to another part of the site. If they go to the relationship index page, they'll see it in the list unless I filter it out.

If the relationship is valid and they do something elsewhere that causes the user to save, that dummy relationship is now a real one. If it's not valid, the save is going to fail for unknown reasons.

I have a number of models I intend to embed in the user, so I will have this issue with every one of them.

I know I can call `current_user.reload` to clear the junk out, but it feels ridiculous to me that I would have to hit the database every time I wanted to do this. I could also orphan the relationship after validating, but that feels hacky.

It seems to me that this is a problem people should run into all the time with embedded documents, so I would think there'd be some kind of built in solution, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134938/rails-deleting-unsaved-associated-records), which is similar to mine, but I want something more extensible, so that I don't have to put it everywhere.

I'm about to make a module that will add a `clear_unsaved_#{relation}` method to the class for each embedded relation, but the idea frustrates me, so I wanted to see if anyone has a better idea of how to do it, and also where is best to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a monkey patch that overrides Mongoid's `embeds_many` and `embeds_one` class methods to also define an instance method for clearing unsaved documents for that relation. This felt like the most straightforward way to me because it's very little code and it means I don't have to remember to include it places.

```rb
# config/initializers/patches/dirty_tracking_embedded.rb
module DirtyTrackingEmbedded
    # override the embedding methods to also make dirty-tracking
    def embeds_many(name, options= {}, &block)
        define_method "clear_unsaved_#{name}" do
            # remove_child removes it from the array without hitting the database
            send(name).each {|o| remove_child(o) unless o.persisted?}
        end
        super
    end

    def embeds_one(name, options={}, &block)
        define_method "clear_unsaved_#{name}" do
            dirty = send(name)
            remove_child(dirty) unless dirty.persisted?
        end
        super
    end
end

module Mongoid
    module Association
        module Macros
            module ClassMethods
                prepend DirtyTrackingEmbedded
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Then in my controller I resorted to an `after_action`:

```rb
# app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
    after_action :clear_unsaved, only: [:new]

    def new
        @relationship = current_user.relationships.new(friend_id: params[:fid])
        @relationship.validate
    end

    private
    def clear_unsaved
        current_user.clear_unsaved_relationships
    end
end
```

## Other Possibilities

### Different monkey patch

You could monkey patch the `setup_instance_methods!` methods in [`Mongoid::Association::Embedded::EmbedsMany`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/association/embedded/embeds_many.rb#L181) and [`Mongoid::Association::Embedded::EmbedsOne`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/association/embedded/embeds_one.rb#L143) to include setting up an instance method to clear unsaved. You can find an example of how the Mongoid folks do that sort of thing by looking at [`Mongoid::Association::Accessors#self.define_ids_setter!`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/association/accessors.rb#L276). I'd recommend doing your patching with a `prepend` like in the solution I went with, so you can inherit the rest of the method.

### Combo monkey patch and inheritance

Mongoid chooses which class to use to instantiate an association from [a constant called `MACRO_MAPPING` in `Mongoid::Association`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/association.rb#L38), so you could make classes that inherit from `EmbedsMany` and `EmbedsOne` with just `setup_instance_methods!` overridden to add the needed instance method, then you would only have to monkey patch `MACRO_MAPPING` to map to your new classes.

### Concern

If you're anti-monkey patching, you could use the code from my `DirtyTrackingEmbedded` module to make an `ActiveSupport::Concern` that does the same thing. You'll want to put the overridden methods in the `class_methods` block, and then just make sure you include this module after you include `Mongoid::Document` in any model class you want it in.